# How to add paths showing turtle movement in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a model that will **tick a stipulated number of times and will move a maximum distance each time**. I've gotten that done, but I can't figure out how to make the model show where the turtle has been using paths connecting the different locations the turtle went to.

I don't even really know if this is possible...? I've googled, searched stack overflow and looked through the Netlogo dictionary and looked through the somewhat helpful textbook I have on hand and can't find anything. I'm sure it's simple, but I just have no idea how to go about it. My current code:

```
to setup
clear-all
;; create turtles on random patches.
ask patch 118 28 [
  sprout 1 [
  set color one-of [green]
  set size 10
  ]
]
reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
   rt random-float 360
   lt random-float 360
   fd random-float 15
]
if ticks = 28 [return]
tick
end

to return
 ask turtles [
  setxy 118 28
 ]
end
```

Comment: Do you just need to see it or do you need to record the locations? If it's just the former, try including `pd` (for `pen-down`) in your `sprout 1 [ ... ]` procedure.

Comment: I just need to see it, so pd might work. I'll give it a shot, thank you!